# Is there a way to play music files from a specific time? (From 0:30 til the end of the track, for example.)

Tags: applications, music-player

I have a Nexus 5 and I'm trying to find out if it is possible to play only certain sections of music files instead of the whole track.

For example, if I want to skip the first 30 seconds, is there any setting I can change for the file or in the music player so that whenever I play that track, it automatically skips the first 30 seconds? Or if I want to play only the segment from 30s to 1:30s for that track, I can specify this is the settings for that track somehow?

I'm currently using the default music player on my phone, but if this is only possible with an app from the Play store, that would be fine with me as well. I browsed through some of the popular apps but they don't make it clear whether or not this feature is present.

Comment: You can cut the mp3 using any mp3 cutter app available in playstore.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't gonna be a the best answer but just Google MP3 cutter. I used one of the apps and they do a good job EDIT: Just select your points and hit 'Start Cut' https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beka.tools.mp3cutter

Comment: You could provide a link to the app you used since there are several.

Comment: There you go this should help